# Create an HQL table from SparkR dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I´m using sparkR from Zeppeling and have the following code:

```
%spark2.r
df <- sql(" select column1 FROM my_schema.my_table")
```

The that dataframe is loaded properly and now I want to 
create a new table on my "my_schema" from there, E.G:

```
my_schema.my_table_from_df
```

For that I´m trying the following:

```
saveAsParquetFile(df, "my_table_from_df.parquet")
```

I´m not getting any error from there, but when I try:

```
%spark2.r
df <- sql(" select column1 FROM my_schema.my_table_from_df")
```

or:

```
%spark2.r
df <- sql(" select column1 FROM my_table_from_df")
```

I get the error:

```
Table or view not found
```

Answer (score 0):

saveAsParquetFile(df, "my_table_from_df.parquet")
I think you write to file. also you need read data with file.
sorry. I don't sparkR

try like
in Scala

```
df.write
  .format("parquet")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable("<database name>.<table name>")
```